# Accessing a class on host

Tags: python, networking, host

Is it possible to access a piece of code on a host? Let's say we have a class on one host and we want to access that class on our computer when running the code (obviously the user at PC should not be able to change any files on the host, we just want to access a file on a host and use it like it's on the user's computer(it should not copy paste the code, just use it as a class in another file)).

Comment: You are asking for if there is any way this can be achieved in Python?

Comment: Yes, and i would like to know how exactly I can do this.